# Dreamhost SSH activity now ip is blacklisted

Tags: ssh, ip, rsync, blacklist, dreamhost

I think that `dreamhost` blacklisted my ip address. I am giving this assumption due to the fact that I can not visit any of the hosted sites on the `dreamhost` server (namor). I also still have an internet connection! Better yet I can view all of the sites through a `proxy`! I'm guessing this has something to do with my workflow of using `SSH` and `RSYNC`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you contact Dreamhost support? Also, did you try turning it off and on again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reasons that should be obvious, only Dreamhost can remove such a block. Contact them.

Comment: Can't access dreamhost.com myself =/

Comment: You say you can access your sites via a proxy, so use that to contact Dreamhost. Or just send an e-mail, or tweet at them.